# mod_rewrite flags that I don't understand

Tags: apache, .htaccess

There a few flags that I have been searching through the internet that I don't seem to understand.

When would you use the [E] flag?

For example.

```
RewriteRule \.jpg$ - [env=dontlog:1]
```

What does that do...?

And how does the NS (No subsequent requests) work? If I have many includes in my php file, do I need to put it the NS so that it doesnt stop it from working? whats use has it got?

Comment: That sets an "environment variable" which you can then read elsewhere in your configuration to conditionally trigger other behavior.  As to what exactly it does, that's defined elsewhere in your config, so we can't really tell you.

Comment: Cant I read it , later on in my htaccess script, set it and then read it.. or keep it between requests and read it ..like a "Session" perhaps

Answer (score 2):

When that rule is matched (`\.jpg%`), an environment variable `dontlog` is set with a value of `1`.

Later, the most likely scenario for how it is used is that the Apache configuration defines a [`CustomLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive which reads that environment variable and does not write a line to the log file when it is set. Therefore, requests for `.jpg` image files are not written to the Apache log.

For example:

```
# Log any request that doesn't have a dontlog variable set...
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```

There is a little bit of information about environment variables [in the mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e)

Directly from said documentation:

> The following example sets an environment variable called 'image' to a value of '1' if the requested URI is an image file. Then, that environment variable is used to exclude those requests from the access log.

```
RewriteRule \.(png|gif|jpg) - [E=image:1]
CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!image
```

Comment: have you got a link to more examples.. I am not familiar with that logging system..nor with the "common" keyword

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd I had been searching for examples but got pulled away... There is only limited info [in the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) I'll see what else I can uncover.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about why the rewrites aren't working, it is because your first rule rewrites the request from index.php to target.php, therefore the second rule will never fire because the requested file is no longer index.php.

The comment already gave you the answer to the environmental variable flag.